# Retrieve numeric fields from sales cloud to perform calculations

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I am looking for a way to retrieve numeric values from sales cloud object fields to perform math calculations in Marketing Cloud.

My code will first get the values for `Audience__c` and `RSVP__c` from campaign object in sales cloud (which is working) and then using these 2 values to perform any simple math calculations.

Extra note: @key I used in RetrieveSalesforceObjects is obtained from my landing page url. (E.g My landing page URL is https://xxx?key=CampaignID)

```
%%[
var @totalaudiencecount, @rsvpcount, @key
SET @key = QueryParameter("key")
SET @totalaudiencecount= RetrieveSalesforceObjects('Campaign', 'Audience__c', 'Id', '=', @key)
SET @rsvpcount= RetrieveSalesforceObjects('Campaign', 'RSVP__c', 'Id', '=', @key)
]%%
```

The above portion is retrieval of sales cloud object field records based on a campaignID, do let me know if my usage of @key is correct. Besides that, I am facing issues to perform calculations from the above numeric fields. Assuming I want to add both values together, how should I proceed from here? I am suspecting the error is due to both values being retrieved as string values. Is there a way to retrieve both values (`Audience__c` and `RSVP__c`) in numeric type instead of string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Ranjdeep's solution as a reference, a sample of the actual solution is just this simple:

```
%%[ 
var @scintfields, @maxcount  

set @scintfields= RetrieveSalesforceObjects('Campaign', 'max_count__c', 'Id', '=', @campaignid)

Set @maxcount = FormatNumber(FIELD(ROW(@scintfields,1), 'max_count__c'),"F0")

]%%
```

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve both the fields in a single call;

```
var @totalaudiencecount, @rsvpcount, @rs, @row

Set @rs= RetrieveSalesforceObjects('Campaign', 'Audience__c, RSVP__c', 'Id', '=', ID)
// Null check
IF NOT Empty(@rs) THEN 
    Set @row = ROW(@rs,1)
    Set @totalaudiencecount = FIELD(@row,"Audience__c")
    Set @rsvpcount = FIELD(@row,"RSVP__c")
ENDIF

VAR @sum
SET @sum = Add(@totalaudiencecount, @rsvpcount)
```

See if this works.

Comment: RetrieveSalesforceObjects returns a rowset/array and you would have to retrieve a row from it before fetching variables.

Comment: Hi Rajdeep, thanks! Appreciate your help :) . However I am getting this error after I run the script in a landing page. 
Error Message:
"500 - Internal server error.
There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed."

Comment: I have also edited the post above to provide more info about how I am using retrievesalesforceobject function. Can you read the post again and let me know if my line of code is correct? Thanks again.